# Getting the bigger polygon of Multipolygon

Tags: polygon, openlayers, geometry, multi-polygon

I have a Multipolygon that has 5 separate polygons and I want to get only the geometry of the biggest polygon.

How can I get the largest polygon from the multipolygon?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you sort the polygons in descending size order it will be the first entry in the array

```
multipolygon.getPolygons().sort(function(polygon1, polygon2) {return polygon2.getArea() - polygon1.getArea();})[0]
```